# Android phone animations have stop working

Tags: applications, samsung, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-5

As title suggests it is a very strange problem I am facing. My phone has stopped showing usual animations instead it just gives jerk effects, or freezes,

**1) for example the traditional google play store animations when you click on any apps,**

**2) another example is of loading bars, which just freezes and doesn't perform its regular animation.**

I have attached small video files to make this more clear with both aforementioned examples.

Another examples to support this are in my android applications which I develop, none of the progress bars or animations work. All loaders just freezes like mentioned in the videos, I use some reveal animation libraries and fancy loaders libraries as well and their animations also don't work.

I checked to see the settings whether I messed up any settings or not but could not find it. Can anyone help me make solution out of this. 
My model is **samsung S5 neo running Android 7.0**.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Google play animations not working]

[image: Progress Loader animation freezes]

Comment: In developer options does changing values of *Windows / Transition animation or Animator duration* make a difference? Wild guess

Comment: Excellent... That was the issue.. I missed it somehow.. but I have never accessed that options so I am not sure how it turned off. But Thank you tons..

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation scale options are turned off in developer options and by turning it on it works as expected..

Comment: There are many options to activate animation. Don't be afraid to select all of them.  
In my Case I select 'Animation Scale 1x' from the list after clicked.
Also, switched off  'Remove/Delete Animations'  from accessibility configuration menu